# Azure Private DNS configuration not working with P2S VPN

Tags: azure, networking, dns, azure-vpn, azure-dns

I have hosted my web application in azure, My team accessing my application vi application gateway private ip using Azure P2P VPN connection. My application is working with private IP, I want to configure dns name and ssl certificates for my private ip.

Following things I have tired so far

1. Created Azure Private DNS Zone and Linked my VNets
2. Created A records for my private ips
3. Added dnssuffixes in azurevpnconfig.xml (Azure VPN Client configuration)
   [image]
4. I tried accessing test.demo.com, I'm getting site not be reached

Not sure what I'm missing

Clarification would be helpful

1. Azure wont support private dns configuration for P2S VPN connection ?
2. Any other workaround to achieve dns and SSL configuration for private IPs ?

Reference :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/64223/issue-with-resolving-hostnames-while-connected-to.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-troubleshoot-vpn-point-to-site-connection-problems

Comment: you are reffering the document of P2S VPN connection and your question is about P2P VPN connection and i don't see anything related to P2P in azure. Azure Only provide P2S and S2S VPN connection if i am not wrong.

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT - Apologies for the typo. I updated the question.  I'm referring P2S VPN connection.

Comment: did you tried the solution provided in lnk : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/64223/issue-with-resolving-hostnames-while-connected-to.html

Comment: As a best practice, do not use a .local domain for your private DNS zone. Not all operating systems support this. : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-overview

Comment: @Debuggger please let me know if above links suggestion works for you or not?

Answer (score 2):

As per [Name resolution for resources in Azure virtual networks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances):

[image]

In order for the P2S VPN clients to be able to resolve Private Endpoint entries hosted on Azure Private DNS Zones, you must leverage an existing DNS Server (Forwarder or Proxy) or deploy one IaaS VM using a DNS Server role. That is required to P2S VPN clients be able to consume Azure Private DNS Zone which is exposed to 168.63.129.16 via DNS Forwarder/Proxy.

Once you have a DNS forwarder/proxy deployed on Azure, you can define the DNS server at the VNET level or set DNS Server configuration directly on client XLM profile. Post this, you will be able to resolve Private Endpoint entries from your P2S clients.

Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns#on-premises-workloads-using-a-dns-forwarder

https://github.com/dmauser/PrivateLink/tree/master/DNS-Integration-P2S